# How to enable required property check on a build component during build time?

Tags: angular

For a project I currently need to switch from React to Angular and I struggle to get a nice DX for my component consumers. I'd like to check at build time if user uses a required property.

In React this is quite easy. I do something like this:

```
type Props = {
  value: number;
};

export const ShowValue: FC<Props> = ({ value }) => (
  <span>{value}</span>
);
```

And if a user writes `<ShowValue />` instead of `<ShowValue value={17} />` an error would be shown.

Can I do something similar in Angular? Given I have something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'show-value',
  template: `
    <span>{{value}}</span>
  `
})
export default class CounterComponent {
  @Input() value: number;
}
```

Is it possible during the build by using TypeScript and/or the Angular AOT compiler to detect incorrect usage like `<show-value></show-value>` and `<show-value value></show-value>` (no value is passed in the last example - I'd need something like `<show-value value="17"></show-value>`).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set an `Input` as required you can add it to the `selector` like below (Source: [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18156#issuecomment-315774348))

```
@Component({
  selector: 'show-value[value]',
  template: `
    <span>{{value}}</span>
  `
})
```

This way the compiler would return an error if `value` is not provided in the template (Ex. `<show-value></show-value>`).

Comment: I saw that workaround before, but I think it would only mark `<show-value></show-value>` as an error, but not `<show-value value></show-value>` (which would be an error as well as I need `<show-value value="17"></show-value>`). I will clarify my question.